# Print a list of objects in C++

Tags: c++, list, class, iterator

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out with regards to printing out a list of a custom class (first time using containers).

Currently I have a variable declared as:

`std::list<Item> inventory;`

within a class called player.

Now I have created a function within the class (player) called `void printInventory();`.

So my question is how do I go about printing what is in that list.

My `Item` class contains 3 variables;

```
std::string name; 
int damage;
int value;
```

I also have a function to print these variables `void itemDetails();`

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:

I know have solved my problem with thanks to the answers provided, here's what i did:

Overloaded the output operator in the item class:

```
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Item& item)
    {
            if (item.getTypeInt() == 0)
            {
                    os << "Name: " << item.getName() << endl
                    << "Type: " << item.getTypeString() << endl
                    << "Damage: " << item.getDamage()<< endl
                    << "Value: " << item.getValue() << endl;
            }
            else
            {
            os << "Name: " << item.getName() << endl
            << "Type: " << item.getTypeString() << endl
            << "HP: " << item.getHP()<< endl
            << "Value: " << item.getValue() << endl;
    }

    return os;
    }
```

I then used one of the answers but modified it so it wasn't declaring another variable:

```
    void Player::printInventory()
    {   
        for(std::list<Item>::iterator it = inventory.begin(); it!= inventory.end(); ++it)
        {
                cout << *it;
        }

        cout <<"Inventroy Printed!!"<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should overload `std::ostream& operator<<` for `Item` and `player`, this will allow you to write the data to streams other than stdout. Here's an example:

```
std::ostream& ooprator<<(std::ostream& os, const Item& item)
{
  return os << "Item {" << item.name << " " << item.damage << " " << item.value << "}";
}
```

This allows you to do

```
Item i;
std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Then, you implement a similar operator for `player`, looping over the list and printing each item.

```
std::ostream& ooprator<<(std::ostream& os, const player& p)
  for (const auto& i : p.inventory) os << i << " "
  return os;
}
```

Comment: +1 for using auto and range for

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `std::for_each` together with `std::mem_fun`. [The MSDN has a nice example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtc0dy7y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Alternatively, you can always roll out your own loop, calling the member function directly.

I have no compiler on my hands, but something like this should do the trick:

```
std::for_each(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), std::mem_fun<Item>(&Item::printInventory));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple for loop

```
for (std::list<Item>::iterator i = inventory.begin(); i != inventory.end(); ++i)
    i->itemDetails();
```

There are other ways, but this is how I'd do it.

`itemDetails` is not a very good name for your method. Maybe `printDetails`?

Answer (score 1):

you already had a list of items in `inventory`. Iterate through it and call `itemDetails`

```
void printInventory()
{
  for(std::list<Item>::iterator it = inventory.begin(); it!= inventory.end(); ++it)
  {
    Item item = *it;
    item.itemDetails();
  }
}
```

This will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the operator `<<` so you'll be able to output an Item through standard output. You can find some examples [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html).

Comment: 'overlap', I like it! But the technically correct term is overload.

Comment: Ooooops! I had other things in my mind... Edited, thanks!